# Kivy support for SDL2 in Virtualenv

Tags: macos, python-3.x, virtualenv, kivy, sdl-2

I followed following steps to install kivy in virtualenv (Mac OSX) with support of sdl2

```
$ brew install sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer
$ pip install -I Cython
$ USE_OSX_FRAMEWORKS=0 pip install kivy
```

but when tried to run basic documentation code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I got following error

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/manthansharma/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-08-25_68.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (default, Aug 16 2016, 05:35:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_gif (img_pygame, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL          ] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider at all!
pygame - ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
  File "/Users/manthansharma/virtualenvs/kivy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/Users/manthansharma/virtualenvs/kivy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pygame.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pygame

pil - ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "/Users/manthansharma/virtualenvs/kivy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/Users/manthansharma/virtualenvs/kivy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pil.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

I also tried to give path of sdl2.dylib in KIVY_SDL2_PATH but not getting any result but using kivy.app works fine but I want to use virtualenv

Comment: Can you post the full compilation log?

Comment: I think its the whole logs

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error on my new Mac (Sierra).
I followed the suggestion at https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4688

and installed the latest version of Kivy using the command
`USE_OSX_FRAMEWORKS=0 pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/zipball/master`

This worked for me, and Kivy is now using SDL2 and not looking for pygame.
Previously, I either needed pygame, but got errors about a "Windows BMP file" when resizing the window, or if I removed pygame, it didn't find the SDL2 I'd installed with brew.

Comment: Thanks, actually problem after installing sdl2 and its dependencies on OSX using brew, it was not linked, so kivy was installed without support for sdl2. Sorry, for not mentioning it here earlier.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at (Kivy didn't find the SDL2 installed via brew). Will you update us with what you did to get it working?

Comment: Could you tell me if you installed python with homebrew? @LindsayWard

Comment: Yes, @hanachan1026, I used homebrew. I imagine it would be the same for brew or other install options.

Comment: Thank you @LindsayWard , I had the same issue as above, what was different from this is I had installed python from pkg since I needed older version of python(brew cannot install older version of python..?) I reinstalled python by macport, and now I solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

After much wheel spinning with homebrew, the only thing that worked for me was to use macports to install the dependencies:

```
sudo port install libsdl2 libsdl2_image libsdl2_ttf libsdl2_mixer
```